# How to use TSPlib to solve traveling salesman problem (TSP)

Tags: java, python, c

I am actually working on TSP problem, and I need to test program, I am using  the data from the TSPlib API(Symmetric traveling salesman problem) :

https://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/tsp/

So I so confused about the data file, for example, is **a280.tsp** represent the coordinates of cities or the distances because when I am using it like coordinate it gives me wrong values,
please, someone can help !!!

Comment: Include the relevant parts of code and ask a more concrete question. This is too broad and not really clear what you want. Read [ask]

Comment: I don't need the code , I want to know if the file  a280.tsp represente a coordinate of cities or distances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line is : node number + x coordinate + y coordinates

```
Node_id x y
```

The content of the `a280.tsp` file is the following (opened with a text editor):

```
NAME : a280
COMMENT : drilling problem (Ludwig)
TYPE : TSP
DIMENSION: 280
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
  1 288 149
  2 288 129
  3 270 133
  4 256 141
  5 256 157
  6 246 157
  7 236 169
  8 228 169
  9 228 161
 10 220 169
    ... 
 280 280 133
 EOF
```

For further details, have a look [here](https://acrogenesis.com/or-tools/documentation/user_manual/manual/tsp/tsp.html#the-instance-file)